# Creating blade file for fields in Backpack?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm new in using Laravel and Backpack. I want to create a blade file for a field in backpack. I want to know to what correspond `$field['name']` in this code ?

```
    @include('crud::fields.inc.wrapper_start')
    <label>Address</label>
    <input
            type="text"
            name="{{ $field['name'] }}[text_address]"
            value="{{ old(square_brackets_to_dots($field['name'].'.text_address')) ?? $field['value']['text_address'] ?? $field['default']['text_address'] ?? '' }}"
            @include('crud::fields.inc.attributes')
    >
    @include('crud::fields.inc.wrapper_end')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you pass as `name` when you add the field will then be available as `$field['name']` inside the field blade file. So if you do:

```php
CRUD::addField([
    'name' => 'title',
    'type' => 'your_custom_type',
]);

// or the same thing using the fluent syntax

CRUD::field('title')->type('your_custom_type');
```

Then inside your `resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/fields/your_custom_type.blade.php` file you'll find that `$field['name']` will be `title`.

PRO TIP: Since most Backpack fields have one input, in default Backpack fields we try as much as possible to use the `$field['name']` as the `name` of the input. That way, it's easier to understand: **the `name` of the field will be the name of the input, which in turn will be saved as the `name` of the model attribute your want to update in the database**. You can use `$field['name']` for whatever you want, but we recommend you use it for the input name too.